# How to frame the rest assured script for a post request based on CURL

Tags: rest-assured

I need to convert the below curl command into rest-assured POST request.
Can someone help me out

```
curl -ks --http1.0 -X POST "$server?format=pdf&tid=TD1" --cookie "INTERSET_SESSION=$access_token" -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' -F 'template=@../templates/dashboard.hbs' -o output.pdf
```

The parameter `template=@../templates/dashboard.hbs` holds a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the below helps

```
{
    RequestSpecification req = RestAssured.given();
    req.header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    req.header("Cookie", "INTERSET_SESSION=ABCD");
    req.multiPart("file2", new File("template=@../templates/dashboard.hbs"));
    Response resp = req.post("$server?format=pdf&tid=TD1");
}
```